# How to create traces that don't touch for a four by four non matrix keyboard grid

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, shift-register, keyboard

[image: keymap]

Hello. I have a potential design for a keyboard whose pcb I will make myself in eagle. This will use cherry mx browns (http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/switches/key/mx.htm for info.  Rather than use a matrix, I will connect each key to the arduino uno via daisy chained shift registers. The only problem I have is how to route connections for each of them without running into connections for other keys, as they will not be laid out in staggered manner. Attached is a rough draft of my layout. Keys on the left are for selecting which function a right key should perform. The three squares and one circle in the bottom left are mouse related and while they will be on the keyboard, they will not be connected via shift register. To summarize, how should I route the key switch-shift register connections?

Comment: Not a single question mark anywhere in there that I can see.  Also an alarming lack of additional punctuation.  I'm sure someone could help you if you question was edited to be clearer and more intelligible.

Comment: @mikeY Done. Sorry for poor quality.

Answer (score 2):

Traces that need to cross on a circuit board are most often handled by using plated through via holes that can jump traces from one side to the other.

If you build your key pad out of tact switches like these they are designed to often have pairs of their terminals shorted across in the switch body. This can perform an automatic trace jump capability for a trace that can pass under the switch body on the circuit board.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention I will be using cherry mx browns, I shall edit the op to make this clear. Would this affect your solution? Does the trace simply go under the switch or on the opposite side of the board for your method?Also, does the diagram represent 1 switch or more?

Comment: The diagram represents one switch just as depicted to the left as the single tact switch. I have no idea what a "cherry mx brown" is so unless you see fit to provide a link to some more information or a link to a data sheet you are pretty much on your own.